# How much time do Moderator's spend working?

Tags: support, moderators, moderation

I have applied to be a moderator on Japanese Language Stack Exchange, but I don't know how much of a time commitment is required. Could anyone give me an idea of how much time a moderator generally spends on a given week doing actual moderation work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience here, but I moderated at philosophy.SE (I have multiple degrees in philosophy)... and moderation in general is not time-consuming in the "takes up two hours at once sense"; instead, it was time-consuming in three respects:

1. Adjudicating the close-worthiness of questions
2. Handling users who were competent but　乱暴している
3. Handling users who misunderstood the SE Q&A system
4. Scope issues related to problems between the popular definition of "philosophy" and what I took to be a working softer version of what the academic discipline is.

My sense is that Japanese.SE has its own transpositions of some of those issues especially with respect to raw translation questions. But I haven't seen as many problematic users (thanks mods!!!) and the scope of this SE is pretty clear.

Comment: Thanks for that, appreciate your input!